# Plotting the Pointwise Max of Multiple Series

Tags: r

I have a csv that I have imported that has multiple data fields for a times series. So the first field is the datetime, and the rest of the fields are variuous datapoints.

How would I plot the pointwise max value of multiple fields, where the fields would be matched on some sort of wildcard?

So for example:

```
time,foo1,foo2,foo3
1:00,1,2,3
2:00,3,1,1
3:00,2,5,3
```

What would be the easiest way to plot `foo.*` such that I get the max from each field: I.e. the resultant plot from that example would be: (1:00,3),(2:00,3),(3:00,5)?

To Clarify the example, the max points I mean are in `**`

```
time,foo1,foo2,foo3
1:00,1,2,*3*
2:00,*3*,1,1
3:00,2,*5*,3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your data are in a data.frame `x`, you can use `pmax` like so:

```
cbind(x[,"time"], do.call(pmax, x[,grepl("^foo*",names(x))]))
```

`do.call` calls the `pmax` function with each column in `x` as a `...` argument (except the first column, which is removed by negative subscripting).  `cbind` combines the first column of `x` with the resulting vector from `do.call`.

Note that the 2nd argument to `do.call` needs to be a list and a data.frame is a list with some extra attributes.  If `x` isn't a data.frame, you'll need to coerce it to one (or a regular list).

Comment: For the other part of my question, are you aware of anyway to filter a  dataframe's columns based on the column name?

Comment: @Kyle - you can use `grepl` to return a logical vector on the column names which can be accessed via `names`. Something like this `dat[, grepl("(foo|bar)", names(dat))]` would return the columns `foo` and `bar` of the data.frame `dat`. R has pretty robust support for regex magic, so I imagine any filtering you needed to do based on column names could be accomplished.

Comment: @Kyle: sorry, I missed that part.  @Chase is spot on.  I've edited my answer to include column selection.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost embarrassing compared to the svelte answer of @Joshua, but I probably would have approached this using `reshape2` and `plyr` had I not been enlightened by the other answer. `melt` turns the data into a "long" format and then `ddply` groups by the time column and selects the max value.

```
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)


dat <- data.frame(time = 1:3, foo1 = c(1,3,2), foo2 = c(2,1,5), foo3 = c(3,1,3))
dat.m <- melt(dat, id.vars = "time")
ddply(dat.m, "time", summarize, max = max(value))
  time max
1    1   3
2    2   3
3    3   5
```

Tests confirm that Joshua's answer is ~30 times faster. The only plausible benefit of my solution is that it may be easier to understand, but that's very subjective. Results:

```
library(rbenchmark)
f_svelte <- function(dat){
  cbind(dat[,1], do.call(pmax, dat[,-1]))

}

f_fat <- function(dat) {
  dat.m <- melt(dat, id.vars = "time")
  ddply(dat.m, "time", summarize, max = max(value))  
}

benchmark(f_svelte(dat), f_fat(dat)
          , columns = c("test", "elapsed", "relative")
          , order = "relative"
          , replications = 500
          )

           test elapsed relative
1 f_svelte(dat)    0.11  1.00000
2    f_fat(dat)    3.59 32.63636
```